# How to retrieve site title from URL in php?

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, forms

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('storeCompany') }}">
   <label>{{ __('Website URL') }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="url" value="{{ old('url') }}" class="form-control" required="required">
   <label>{{ __('Site Title') }}</label>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control" required="required">
   <input type="submit" name="sbNewReviewItem" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="{{ __('Submit') }}">
</form>
```

So This is my form and I want the Site title field to be auto-completed (It must be editable as well) according to the Website URL.

Example: I enter `https://stackoverflow.com/` as the Website title and then the site title must show `Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers` (Site title) in the Site title field. Please let me know if you know a method to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Hope this below answer will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](https://paiza.io/projects/XZwGALdsIIr_Rf3jxRYXfg) For this function you can get title name using url.

### **For this function you can get title name using url**

---

```
<?php
    function page_title($url) {
        $fp = file_get_contents($url);
        if (!$fp) 
            return null;

        $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
        if (!$res) 
            return null; 

        // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
        $title = trim($title);
        return $title;
    }
    print page_title("https://stackoverflow.com");
?>
```

**OUTPUT : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers**

## **LARAVEL CODE**

### **HTML code**

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" action="{{ route('storeCompany') }}"  id="websiteForm">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label>{{ __('Website URL') }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="url" value="{{ old('url') }}" class="form-control url"  required="required">
    <label>{{ __('Site Title') }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control title"/>
    <input type="submit" name="sbNewReviewItem" class="btn btn-block btn-primary clssubmit" value="{{ __('Submit') }}">
</form>
```

### **Route code**

---

```
Route::post('changestatus', ['as' => 'changestatus', 'uses' => 'YourControllerName@changestatus']);
Route::post('checktitle', ['as' => 'checktitle', 'uses' => 'YourControllerName@checktitle']);
```

### **Controller code**

---

```
public function checktitle(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $data = self::page_title($request->val);   
        $arr = array("status" => 200, "msg" => 'success',"result" => $data);
    } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
        $msg = 'Something went wrong.';
        if (isset($ex->errorInfo[2])) {
            $msg = $ex->errorInfo[2];
        }
        $arr = array("status" => 400, "msg" => $msg, "result" => array());
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $msg = 'Something went wrong.';
        if (isset($ex->errorInfo[2])) {
            $msg = $ex->errorInfo[2];
        }
        $arr = array("status" => 400, "msg" => $msg, "result" => array());
    }
    return \Response::json($arr);
}

private function page_title($url) {
    $fp = file_get_contents($url);
    if (!$fp) 
        return null;
    $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
    if (!$res) 
        return null; 
    // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
    $title = trim($title);
    return $title;
}
```

### **Ajax code**

---

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.url', function (e) {
   var val= $( ".url" ).val( );
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       url: "{{ route('checktitle')}}",  // write your route path
       headers: {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
       data: {val : val},
       type: 'POST',
       beforeSend: function () {
             $('.clssubmit').prop("disabled", true);
       },
       success: function (data) {
           if (data.status == 400) {
             $('.submitspinner').html('');
             toastr.error(data.msg)
           }
           if (data.status == 200) {
             $('.clssubmit').prop("disabled", false);
             $( ".title" ).val(data.result);
             toastr.success(data.msg)
           }
       },
   });
});
```

Comment: Hope this answer is work for you!! @Codenooober

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to get content of `<title>` tag by `document.title`. Then, you can push this to the corresponding `<label>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You will get your answer here [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php][1]

`$tags = get_meta_tags('https://stackoverflow.com/');

print_r($tags);`

Answer (score 0):

Blade template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('storeCompany') }}"  id="websiteForm">
        @csrf
        <label>{{ __('Website URL') }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="url" value="{{ old('url') }}" class="form-control" required="required">
        <label>{{ __('Site Title') }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control name"/>
        <input type="submit" name="sbNewReviewItem" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="{{ __('Submit') }}">
    </form>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bZS47S7sPOxkjU/4Bt0zrhEtWx0y0CRkhEp8IckzK+ltifIIE9EMIMTuT/mEzoIMewUINruDBIR/jJnbguonqQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

        <script>
            $("#websiteForm").submit(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                var bodyFormData = new FormData(this);
                var url=$(this).attr('action');
                axios.post(url,bodyFormData).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    $('input[name="title"]').val(response.data.title)


                    return false;
                }).catch(function (error) {



                });


            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In **Laravel side**

```
 if(request()->isMethod('POST')){

        $html = file_get_contents(request()->url);

       

        $xml = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $xml->validateOnParse = true;
        $xml->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));


        return  [
            'title'=>$xml->getElementsByTagName('title')->item('0')->nodeValue,

        ];

    }
```